# Unable to push first repo to Gitlab.com

Tags: git, gitlab

I've created an account on Gitlab, set up an SSH key and can fetch from my new project URL - but I can't push :( - if I use HTTPS I get:

```
Writing objects: 100% (375/375), 84.82 MiB | 11.22 MiB/s, done.
Total 375 (delta 182), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; result=55, HTTP code = 0
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I use SSH I get a `TortoiseGitPlink Fatal Error` message: `Server unexpectedly closed network connection` - and this in my Git output:

```
Compressing objects: 100% (359/359), done.
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' writeatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
 error: Invalid argument
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com: [snip]'
```

It is quite a big repository. I've tried getting a newer version of TortoiseGitPlink but that didn't help.

Comment: I've just created a test repo and pushed a change - so all my config is OK - it's obviously a problem with the size of the repo or something. I supposedly have 10Gb free - right!?

Comment: it's a network issue so do this verbose option to know the details 
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push

Comment: @Inforedaster thx - will try later!